# Editing billing and shipping addresses individually

Tags: php, magento

I have question regarding a proposed change we are considering to the way a *new* customer account works with regards to their billing and shipping address. When a new account is created, the one form the user fills in for their address goes towards *both* their billing and shipping address.

When they attempt to edit billing, shipping gets changed. If they edit shipping, billing gets changed. Our customer support team gets phone calls on this quite a bit.

I am proposing to modify how this works so that editing the billing address changes only billing and editing shipping address changes only shipping. However, we have been told if we do that, it will make it easier for fraud. I don’t understand how since, by default, one can Add A New Address and assign it to shipping, so why not allow them to just make an edit change to shipping and not have it change billing?

Maybe there is more going on here than I realize?

Thanks for any help…

Answer (score 0):

The reason this increase the chance of fraud is because if you have a stolen credit card number and you obviously have to have the billing address of the original owner of the credit card. The billing address is always going to be the actual address of the person unless it is a hacker and they have logged into the bank's website and changed the billing address, which I have seen done.

So if you force the billing and shipping address to be the same it basically renders most stolen credit card numbers useless, because if someone stole the number they wouldn't want to buy it but then have it shipped to the actual owners address.

This really isn't a programming question though, you may want to go ahead and delete the question.